Story: Maharal, Naftali, Ginger and Laughter
I heard a story by the Maharal (iirc), regarding a non-Jewish official visiting, and the Maharal showed him a vision of the 12 shevatim on the condition that he wouldn't laugh, and apparently when he saw Naftali (iirc) running, with his ginger (red) hair, he laughed.
I don't really remember any more details, but I would like to know the full story, and what the lesson in it was?

interesting... I wonder if any connection to the idea of the lost tribes being sometimes called רויטע יידן in Yiddish

I remember reading that story in the Maharals biography many years ago  by Yaacov Dovid Shulman published by CSI (i dont have the book so I cant look it up for you, sorry)

@Efraym very like where I read it too, but I don't remember which book so thanks very much for the lead. Do you remember the story?

@RabbiKaii no sorry
